# how to know IPs available on a server?

Tags: linux, ip

I think there used to be a command to do that but I forget.

Something like ipconfig in windows.

My server has 10 available IPs and I want to know them all.

Comment: `ifconfig`  or `ip a s`

Comment: @UlrichDangel The Q&A is simple, but that is still the answer.

Comment: `ip r l`  .......... :)

Comment: @jordanm i couldn't really believe it and didn't feel like writing a lot of text around it.

Comment: @UlrichDangel I would have just pasted some example output to "pad" the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are only interested in the IP addresses but not the other gory details about the network interfaces, `/sbin/ifconfig -a | grep "inet addr:" |awk '{print $2}'|cut -d: -f2` gives you all the ip addresses configured on all network interface cards and nothing else.

Comment: This works perfectly.

Comment: `grep | awk | cut` is pretty bad. `awk` can do the job of all 3 of those tools.

Answer (score 2):

Below are some command to extract only IP addresses :

```
ifconfig | awk -F':' 'NR==2{split($2,a," "); print a[1]}'

ip -f inet addr show dev eth0 | sed -n 's/^ *inet *\([.0-9]*\).*/\1/p'

ifconfig eth0 | sed -n 's/^ *inet addr:*\([.0-9]*\).*/\1/p'
```

To check Public IP

```
curl ifconfig.me
```

Comment: This is actually the most complete solution. However, I've tried and tested Mel's solution.

Answer (score 1):

`/sbin/ifconfig -a` 'll show you your network interface(s) with details including the IP address.

Answer (score 1):

```
ifconfig
```

if you have a problem, try

```
man ifconfig
```